# Google Fusion Tables from iOS app / Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-fusion-tables

I started developing ios application that integrate with google fusion tables. I searched both [google gdata](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) and [google client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) libraries but they do not offer fusion tables. On google groups they say "gtm-http-fetcher and gtm-oauth2 libraries could be helpful" but did not find more. Can you please advice me or point me to a example? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like they say :), there's no official Google Obj-C API for Fusion Tables so in your app you should use an authenticated `GTMHTTPFetcher` instance to communicate with the Fusion Tables API v1.0 via HTTP requests. Depending on what your app needs to do, you might also have to use other Google APIs such as the Drive SDK for setting your Fusion Tables permissions.

A quick conceptual overview of how to use the gtm-http-fetcher and gtm-oauth2 libraries in your app:

1. set your desired access scope: `[GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:...`
2. use `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` controller for authentication: `[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:...`
3. retrieve the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` instance, for subsequent usage it can also be saved to / retrieved from iOS keychain
4. use the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` auth to authenticate an `GTMHTTPFetcher` instance
5. now you can use the `GTMHTTPFetcher` to submit HTTP requests to Fusion Tables API v1.0 as described [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using)

Comment: OK thanks! I will try this then come back with more questions :)

Comment: as it might be relevant to this as well as to other related questions, thought I'd also point out to the [Obj-C-FusionTables project](https://github.com/akpw/Obj-C-FusionTables) on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

For development need of Google Fusion tables you can go through this [Google Fusion Tables For Developers](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/)

You can integrate it with other things in such a manner :- [Create With Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/184641)

Finally Sample code you can find here [Sample code Fusion tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#ftAPIv1). This code is not specific to iOS / Objective C. But uses the REST services so you can call them from iOS app via web services and get data in JSON/XML.

Hope this helps you !